# What is the correct way to say missile?

Tags: pronunciation

What is the correct pronunciation of the word "missiles"  because some sites say "mis-uh l" while some others say "mis-i oh"

Comment: The pronunciation depends very much on the county where you were raised. Did those speakers intend an allusion to a [**missal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missal)?

Comment: Hopefully, the correct way to speak about a missile is **miss-all**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!
m-w.com writes the following. Most common is "miss-uhls", accepted though less common is the British "miss-Ils" (pronounced like the words "miss" and "aisles").

Comment: Brits think that "missul" inhabits the same space that "nukular" does.